# QGIS - SpatialLite - Trigger for code correspondences - Manage multiple results

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite, trigger

I have a database containing correspondences between codes (e.g., A = 1 = 11 = H = M, etc.). I've made the first 100 rows of this data available for download.

[BDD Extract](https://fromsmash.com/BDD-Extract)

I would like a feature where, upon entering codes in my working layer, the system automatically matches them with the relevant fields when saved.
For instance, if I input "A" in the "EUNIS" field, I want it to match with "CORINE" (=1), HIC (=11), "ZH" (=H), "EUNIS22" (=M), and so on, based on the contents of the "BDD" layer.

Since the database is large, I believe the most efficient way to handle this is through SQL layers, possibly using SpatialLite layers.

Currently, I can obtain results for exact matches. I used this trigger :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine1
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_1 ON HABITAT_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITAT_POLY
    SET CORINE_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM BDD_Extract WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1)
    WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1;
END;
```

However, I'm unsure how to manage multiple matches. I prefer not to allow modifying the "CORINE" field manually.
Instead, I want QGIS to suggest a list of codes for each instance with multiple matches. The user can then choose the appropriate code manually (e.g., if A1.11 matches with 11.1, 11.2, and 11.3, a list of these three results should be presented for the user to choose from).

I'm quite open to any solution, maybe SpatialLite isn't fit for this situation.

Comment: Here is a link to my final solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470679/qgis-load-dynamic-dropdown-list-from-the-content-of-another-field-using-separat/471229#471229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the link to my final solution, so I can resolve this issue :
[QGIS load dynamic dropdown list from the content of another field, using separator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470679/qgis-load-dynamic-dropdown-list-from-the-content-of-another-field-using-separat/471095?noredirect=1#comment769839_471095)